# Build failed with fresh installed react-native app

Tags: android, react-native

Im trying to build an app but run into some problems so tried with a fresh projects that still fails to build. This is my steps:

1) Installing the app with

```
react-native init Myapp
```

after that Im running the emulator in android studio and launching the app with:

```
react-native run-android
```

and are getting the errormessage below. I have tried to reinstall the react-native cli

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

reset the cache in gradle with

```
cd android
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

It used to work but since I have had some problems to build the apk I messed around a bit with the gradle. I might have updated something that causes the error. Any help is very welcomed!

here is the errormessage

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for org.webkit:android-jsc.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jitpack.io/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/org/webkit/android-jsc/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/org/webkit/android-jsc/'. Received status code 522 from server: Origin Connection Time-out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose 
flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for org.webkit:android-jsc.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jitpack.io/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/org/webkit/android-jsc/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/org/webkit/android-jsc/'. Received status code 522 from server: Origin Connection Time-out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (D:\Myapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
    at buildAndRun (D:\Myapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at then.result (D:\Myapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Did the execution statement run inside the project folder?

Answer (score 0):

Is Android SDK installed and are all the required variables set?
Try running in the command line:

```
adb
```

If the command is not recognized, then something is wrong with your Android SDK installation.

Follow the [link provided in the error](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment) for detailed instructions on installing Android SDK.

Comment: yes that did run without any problems. It used to work then suddenly it didnt. Maybe after I tried to upgrade the gradle. Now it is says 

'dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")'

In build gradle

Answer (score 0):

I think, Developer options  closed in your devices first open developer options,

then  try this command

1. react-native init Test
2. npm i
3. react-native run-android or ios.

Comment: that didnt work unfortuantely. very strange. Is there a way to reset everything. Uninstall react and gradle and all and startover?

Answer (score 0):

- Turn off wifi
- Build the app in offline mode
- Turn on wifi
- Your app should be builded

The reason behind this has been described here: https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/2490

Answer (score 0):

Go to android folder and edit **build.gradle**

set  buildToolsVersion to `buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"` mine was 30.0.2 when i changed it to **"23.0.1"** it started working

In the **android** folder run

```
gradlew.bat installDebug
```

and make sure the **Build is successful**

[image]

That should do it go back to your project folder and run

```
npm run android
```